# 権威レファレンスが必要とは？

Tags: サポート

質問の[リビジョン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/14278/revisions)で次のようなメッセージを見かけました:

> 通知が削除されました 権威レファレンスが必要 by [Community♦](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)

この`権威レファレンスが必要`とはどういうことでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[お礼](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)の設定時に選べる理由の一つで、[原文](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/)はこれです。

> **Authoritative reference needed**
>
> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

で現在の訳がこうなっているわけですが…

> **権威レファレンスが必要**
>
> 信頼できる、または公式の情報源から入手した回答を探しています。

訳し直すとしたらこんな感じでしょうか。説明文は現状のままでもいいかもしれませんが。

> **信頼できる情報を求めています**
>
> 公式などの信頼できる情報源に基づいた回答を探しています。

Comment: 誤訳だとは思いました。やっぱり`権威レファレンスが必要`は訳し直したほうがいいですね。